# Rigidbody capsule takes off into space along Y axis

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a capsule that I use as a player with no script attached.  When I hit play it shoots up along the Y axis.
I have no collision enabled.  When I disable the "Use Gravity" it doesn't fly away but I need the use gravity because I'm going to be adding a player movement script.  I'm sure it has to do with gravity but I'm not sure what I need to adjust.  Any ideas what I need todo so this won't happen?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like your gravity goes upwards? Could you show your Physics Settings?

Comment: Your question got me to look at physic settings.  I noticed the Y was set to 30.  That's what was causing it to fly up.  THANK YOU!  @derHugo